# Textarea losing focus even if I try to keep it

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I have a very interesting situation.
This is my component:

```
export const checkbox = ({ data }) => {
    const inputRef = useRef(null);
    
    console.log(inputRef); // Does not appear
    return (
            <FormGroup>
                {data.data.map(item => (
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Input
                                ref={inputRef}
                            />
                        </FormGroup>
            </FormGroup>
    );
};
```

It is a child of other component which basically get values and submits to form.

but to no avail..
How can I fix this? I just need it to keep the focus, so I can continue typing. Should I use [React.memo()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate) for this?
Also, please note that I have checked all the references I could find on SO and nothing helped. I have spent 3 days on this.

Comment: Could you  please post an example on codesandbox? Calling `.focus` is usually a bad idea

Comment: @Dupocas  Do you want me to c/p this entire code on codesandbox?

Comment: If you can. Doesn't need to be a complete example. just the relevant code.

Comment: Unless there's something wrong with your ```Input``` component, passing that handler you have commented shouldn't affect focus whatsoever. Are you using a library for your inputs?

Comment: @Dupocas, does this help: https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-violet-9mfbf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisB., yes, Reactstrap.

Comment: It's just a blank screen right now

Comment: For me it works ok..: https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-violet-9mfbf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Perhaps I don't understand how codesandbox works..

Comment: Can you share what your `data` prop looks like? Why are you iterating over `data.data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our chat, the root cause was elements having a dynamic `key` prop which changed on each render. This was causing a new textarea element to be rendered with each change event and the new element didn't have focus.

The solution is to use a deterministic key which doesn't change between renders.